# unable to install FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions on 64 bit win server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am trying to publish website (asp.net 4.0, IIS 5, win server 2003 64 bit) from my machine to server 2003 and getting error **'The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed '**.

I have followed the following steps but somehow can't see FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions checkbox under IIS details.

click Add/Remove Windows Components

Click on "Application Server" and click "Details"

Click on "IIS" and then "Details"

Why can't i see the option for 'FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions'?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: IIS 5 on server 2003 ???

Comment: i have checked the version and it says version 5.2....I have also added the screen shot of IIS on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391382/unable-to-install-frontpage-2002-server-extensions

Comment: **(1)** First off all, please don't cross-post on Stack Exchange sites, it makes a mess.  **(2)** Second of all, I'll edit the picture into your question.  **(3)** Third, and **MOST IMPORTANTLY**, that's not version 5.2 of IIS, nor do you (seem to) have FrontPage 2002 Extensions installed... you have WebDAV, which replaced FrontPage Extensions when that line got obsoleted, ***AND*** `Version 5.2 (Build [blah] : Service Pack 2)` indicates your OS version, which is Server 2003, SP2.  We're going to need you to provide useful, *correct* information to help you with your problem.

Comment: @HopelessN00b, thanks for your comments and editing my question. Sorry i wasn't aware that IIS 6.0 is a Built-in component of Windows Server 2003. Can i still use front page extention on IIS 6.0 to avoid VS2010 error 'The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed '?

Answer (score 2):

You may not find this helpful, but **I** would **recommend, in the strongest possible terms,** ***not*** doing a new installation of software that's a decade old and currently five major versions behind (for the OS) or obsoleted (for FrontPage extensions) - do you actually need to install such an old version of IIS (2.5 versions behind) on such an old OS and an even older version of the FrontPage extensions?

For one thing, [`IIS 5.0` doesn't use FrontPage 2002 extensions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318287), aside from everything else wrong with, in 2012, publishing a website from Server 2003 (5 major versions behind and 9 years behind) using `IIS 5.0` (2.5 major versions and 12 years behind) and FrontPage 2002 extensions ([obsoleted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontPage_Server_Extensions) and a decade old).

For another, `IIS 5.0` is not supported on Server 2003, which introduced IIS 6.  (I know it can be forced to work from past <strike>traumas</strike> experiences I haven't yet managed to obliterate from my conscious mind with ethanol.)

The minimum supported IIS version on 2003 is `IIS 6.0`, which has an option to run in `IIS 5.0 isolation mode` for compatibility with applications that require `IIS 5.0`.  Unless that isn't providing the compatibility you need, you definitely want to update your IIS version as far as you can for compatibility with... anything reasonably modern.

Having said all that, see [this MS KB on ASP.NET/FrontPage 2003 extensions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832095) for what is probably your problem, if you're still determined to continue down this path of... certain, impending pain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right i think i should install IIS 6.0 instead of version 5.0. Does IIS 6.0 comes with Front Page extention? I mean would i be able to publish website remotely through VS2010 (with or without extention on IIS 6.0)?

Comment: Does IIS 6.0 comes with window server 2003?

Comment: @user1263981  I don't think it's installed by default, but if you want to "install" it, you should be able to add it through the `Add/Remove Windows components` wizard in the `Control Panel`, which may require popping the Server 2003 install CD (or CD2 with the optional components) into the CD tray if you didn't cache the `i386` directory on the hard disk somewhere.

Comment: i have tried server 2003 cd but still there is no option to install Front Page Server Extensions.

Comment: @user1263981 Right, you's use the CD to install IIS 6.  Once that's done, you can install or worry about the WebDAV/FrontPage installation.

Comment: front page extention is not available in 64 bit server so i am going to try following steps given in this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891314